# neon assembly vector instructions that affect flags

Tags: assembly, simd, neon

I use arm assembly and NEON SIMD instructions. I want to get the maximum of 16 bit unsigned values which are in two Q registers and compare them with a threshold. If all the 16 bit values are smaller than the threshold, I call a function. If one or more values are larger than a threshold, I call another function.

The following SIMD instructions gets the maximum.

// threshold is an r register

```
vdup.16       q15, threshold  
vmax.u16      q12, q14, q13  
vcgt.u16      q11, q12, q15
```

Does vcgt affect the FPSCR flags? I think not. Then I have to check if q11 is zero or not. If it is zeor, call function1, otherwise call function2.
It would be like

```
if (q11 == 0)
//call function1
else
//call function2
```

How can I do it without moving q11 to 4 r registers?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any - at least not in the user mode.
Those cmp instructions create mask vectors that you choose values between two results based upon.

1. create a mask with the appropriate vcmp
2. calculate results for both cases
3. use the mask from 1 to put the corresponding elements to each lane from both results above.

Currently I cannot tell you precisely what the instructions are since I'm writing this on my iPhone in a train. But it won't be a problem finding them in the reference manual.

Comment: I don't want to calculate the results for both cases. I want to increase the speed of my program by choosing only one case at a time based on the threshold. That's why, I posted my question. I will find another way. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I found another way by narrowing the value in q13 and then do vector compare with zero.

Comment: You should avoid any kind of function calls while NEON is at work anyway. As soon as an ARM register accesses the memory (which WILL occur in function calls), it will cause pipeline stalls which usually waste about 12 cycles.

Comment: ... Not to mention that for every function call you (or your compiler) would also need to store all of the appropriate Q registers to the stack to avoid corruption by the called function.  This is why most DSP kernels are leaf functions.  It's very inefficient to do what you describe.  Easier to do what Jake suggests and just inline your function.

Comment: Another idea for vectorizing your algorithm is to put the results of all your compares in an array of essentially booleans.  When the function returns, the calling function can iterate over the array of results, and call the appropriate sub-function.

Comment: Thank you for your answers guys. You are absolutely correct. I use macros instead of function calls.